# Как убрать определенный символ в начале строки?

Tags: sql, oracle

Мне надо убрать из таблицы где в начале есть «-».

Например:

```
-AFRICA  
-AMERICA
-MOLDOVA
```

Мне надо чтобы эти слова показывали без «-» вот так:

```
AFRICA
AMERICA
MOLDOVA
```

Как это сделать, помогите?

```
select t.code,SMM_FUNCTIONS.Transliteration(t.descr) from ESI_SD_DICTIONARIES$SM t
where t.name = 'COUNTRC'
group by t.code,t.descr
```

Comment: Обратите внимание на комментарий @0xdb к моему ответу. Если в начале может быть несколько минусов подряд (например, `---MOLDOVA`) ответ может Вам не подойти.

Comment: А откуда берётся "-"? Вы пишите "убрать из таблицы", а выводите результат функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать с помощью CASE. Например, так:

```
select (case
         when countries.descr like '-%' then
          --если начинается с «-» то убираем его
          substr(countries.descr, 2)
         else
          countries.descr
         end) as country_name
from (select t.code, SMM_FUNCTIONS.Transliteration(t.descr) as descr
      from ESI_SD_DICTIONARIES$SM t
      where t.name = 'COUNTRC'
      group by t.code,t.descr) countries
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @RaduDrosu Пожалуйста!

Comment: Меня что-то сомнения терзают, а не проще ли - `ltrim(descr, '-')`?

Comment: @0xdb Проще и в данном случае действительно может подойти. `ltrim` отличается от моего варианта тем, что уберет все минусы в начале: `---USA` станет `USA`, а не `--USA`. Попробуйте опубликовать ответ, может это и правильно.

Comment: Тогда так - `regexp_replace(descr, '^-')`.

Comment: @0xdb Да, хороший вариант. Оформите ответом

Comment: Пока не совсем понятно, обратите внимание на мой комментарий под вопросом и то, что это поле в group by.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490), или создайте свою пользовательскую функцию:

```sql
with 
function ltrimOne (s varchar2, ch char:=' ') return varchar2 is
begin
    if substr (s, 1, 1) = ch then return substr (s, 2); 
    else return s; 
    end if;
end;
countries (descr) as (
    select (column_value).getStringVal ()  
    from xmlTable ('"-AFRICA", "-AMERICA","-MOLDOVA"')
)
select regexp_replace (descr, '^-') descr, ltrimOne (descr, '-') descr2
from countries
/
```

Результат:

```
DESCR    DESCR2  
-------- --------
AFRICA   AFRICA  
AMERICA  AMERICA 
MOLDOVA  MOLDOVA
```

Comment: может стоит еще добавить вариант с `ltrim()`? По формулировке вопроса не совсем понятно - нужно удалять только строго один `-` символ вначале строки или все `-`. Во втором случае `ltrim()` отработает IMO быстрее...

Comment: @MaxU Это я уже предлагал в комментарии. Раз ТС принял с одним "-", ну значит так тому и быть.